# Trying to read a file doesn't find it

Tags: java, path, bufferedreader, filereader

So I am trying to read a file using BR and FR but all the time get an error that it can not find a file. I think that the problem is with path but idk what is it.
Please help 
I am working on Mac OS 10.7.5 Lion 
Tried to put a file directly into project, problem still occurs

```
class FileReadre {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File MyFile = new File("//Users//User//Desktop//MyFile.txt");

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(MyFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            line = br.readLine();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found: " + MyFile.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't read the file: " + MyFile.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped. You don't need double forward slashes.